# Automatically generate typescript api from spring boot rest controllers

Tags: spring, typescript, maven, swagger-codegen

I'm currently working on autogenerating typescript-angular code from a .json definition file.
I figured out, that swagger automatically tags my REST Controllers by their names and writes it the definition file when I visit the `/v2/api-docs` page from swagger. The result is, that the codegen tool generates multiple service files which is cool.

The tool from `kongchen` which generates this json during compile time doesn't do that. So it just writes all endpoints but doesn't tag it in the correct form so everything just goes into the same `default.service.ts` file.

Is there maybe anything I missed? So in the end I want to have a swagger definition file which includes tags so that no big `default.service.ts` gets generated but `user.service.ts`, `pet.service.ts`  etc.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <apiSources>
                    <apiSource>
                        <springmvc>true</springmvc>
                        <locations>
                            <location>com.project.main.Controller</location>
                        </locations>
                        <schemes>http</schemes>
                        <host>localhost:9999</host>
                        <basePath>/</basePath>
                        <info>
                            <title>Swagger Maven Plugin Spring Boot for cars</title>
                            <version>v1</version>
                            <description>Working sample of Spring Boot for cars annotations</description>
                            <termsOfService>
                                http://www.githubproeas.com
                            </termsOfService>
                            <contact>
                                <email>carsexample@email.com</email>
                                <name>Cars Example</name>
                                <url>http</url>
                            </contact>
                            <license>
                                <url>http://www.license.com</url>
                                <name>License name</name>
                            </license>
                        </info>
                        <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
                        <swaggerDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</swaggerDirectory>
                    </apiSource>
                </apiSources>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I have heard about *spring-rest-2-ts*, it may help you, i have not tried it till now but if it helps, please replay here